# How to show that a matrix is the eigenvector matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

I have the matrix $$\mathrm{T}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
e^{B+J} & e^{-J} \\
e^{-J} & e^{-B+J}
\end{array}\right]$$
With the eigenvalues:
$$\lambda_{1,2}=e^{J} \cosh (B) \pm \sqrt{e^{2 J} \sinh ^{2}(B)+e^{-2 J}}, \quad \cot (2 \phi)=e^{2 J} \sinh (B), \quad 0<\phi<\frac{\pi}{2}$$
And I would like to show that $$S=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\cos \phi & -\sin \phi \\
\sin \phi & \cos \phi
\end{array}\right)$$
Is the matrix of eigenvectors for $T$. What would be the simplest way to show this?

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake. Of eigenvectors, I mean

Comment: The *simplest* way is to plug in ```{{E^(b + j), E^(-j)}, {E^(-j), E^(-b + j)}}``` in Wolfram Alpha. Otherwise it's just the usual $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ algebra, etc.

Comment: Are there any other facts about $B,J$? For example, do they commute?

Comment: I managed to solve it in the end, with quite a bit of trig-algebra. :)